# Transferring code from a file "main.py " in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to run the code in Jupiter notebook, but the figures in it do not run, help me to display the BTC graph in the pandas DataFrame using the "matplotlib" library

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.show()

xdata = []
ydata = []


def update_graph():
   ax.plot(xdata, ydata, color='g')
   ax.legend([f"Last price: {ydata[-1]}$"])

   fig.canvas.draw()
   plt.pause(0.1)


async def main():
    url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@miniTicker"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
        while True:
           data = json.loads(await client.recv())['data']

           event_time = time.localtime(data['E'] // 1000)
           event_time = f"{event_time.tm_hour}:{event_time.tm_min}:   
           {event_time.tm_sec}"

           print(event_time, data['c'])

           xdata.append(event_time)
           ydata.append(int(float(data['c'])))

           update_graph()


if __name__ == '__main__':
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Is there an error? If so, please paste it _in full_ into the question.

Comment: Good afternoon!
Thank you, indicated below in the attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter runs your code differently than normal Python does.

When you run your code with `python myfile.py`, it sets a variable called `__name__` to `main`. But when Jupyter runs your code, it doesn't set the variable.

Thus, when you say `if __name__ == '__main__'`, it will never be executed in Jupyter because `__name__` will never be `main`.

So, the solution is to remove the `if` statement and just keep the lines under it.

Change

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

to

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Good afternoon!
Thank you very much, I deleted this. There was a problem with running the figure fig = plt.figure() in jupiter notebook.
- /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this statement: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon!
I post an error at startup:

- /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

[Click to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVCWg.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).